# eclipse servlet java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I keep getting this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet when I attempt to run my servlet in eclipse.

I am using the web version of eclipse in conjunction with Tomcat.  I have servlet-api.jar in the library, as well as javaee-6.0.jar imported (though I believe I am using java 7, this was the most recent version of this I could find)

[image]

So why do I keep getting this error?  I've scoured the web and the solution has always been servlet-api.jar, but I have this file in the library to no benefit.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is that error happing during the compilation or during the run?

Did you configure Eclipse to point to the Tomcat server? In order to run a web server in eclipse using tomcat, you need to tell eclipse about tomcat first. 
Here is where you ca find the instruction. http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html

Comment: Eclipse knows about tomcat, and tomcat attempts to run it, but as it's starting up, I get this classnotfound exception.

Comment: I see. What I would suggest now is to just run the homepage of tomcat inside eclipse. If it says the same error, then obviously the jar is missing somewhere.

Comment: This is kind of embarrassing, I am quite new at all this, and have only ever made a servlet with tomcat and eclipse before.  How do I run the homepage from eclipse?  Thank you for your patience

Comment: No worries. Eclipse has an embedded browser, where for URL you can just enter the URL of your tomcat homepage, which is usually: http://localhost:8080. 8080 is the default port; if you use a different, then change it to the one you use. To trigger to eclipse's browser, simply write a simple HTML file, then right click on it and choose to Open With -> Web Browser. Also, make sure you are in J2EE perspective of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, it was working at localhost.  The issue was something with eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have your servlet-api.jar you most probably dont need to bundle it with your war. Generally tomcat uses it own servlet-api, which is located ./common/lib/servlet-api.jar.

Most probably you are missing this, which causes the ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Oh yeah, I definitely should have mentioned that this does not seem to exist for me.  While Tomcat certainly attempts to run, the only Tomcat folder I have is C:\Tomcat, and the only thing in C:\Tomcat is another folder called webapps.  It's completely empty besides that.  What does this mean?

Comment: Something very strange about your tomcat setup. Empty folder like you just mentioned will not even let you start the tomcat. However it seems you can. Have you integrated your tomcat as a remote server ?. I'm pretty sure the problem is with your tomcat, not your web app. Read some tutorial on how to integrate eclipse-tomcat, and double check your tomcat settings

Comment: I think you're right, it's probably something to do with Tomcat.  To the best of my knowledge, I don't have it as a remote server.  I've put it on so many machines before, I barely even remember whether or not I've ever run something on this one.  I'm going to re-install Tomcat and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Oh wait, I found a different folder in my downloads folder called apache-tomcat which has everything (how disorganized of me).  This has servlet-api.jar in its lib folder

Comment: try deploying your webapp manually in to tomcat(without eclipse) see if that works. Check the server logs or the console for errors.

Comment: I ran startup.bat from tomcat's bin folder, and tried going to localhost in my browser, and nothing came up.  I've never tried to run Tomcat in this way before, but I know what localhost should look like when Tomcat is successfully running.  I'm thinking I just have to re-install Tomcat or something

Answer (score 0):

You correctly have added servlet.jar and javaee.jar. The error you specified is typically happens when one of those two files are missing. However, since you have those files, I recommend doing the following:

- Removed the jar files and add them back in to your project
  [image]
- Once you added them back in then do a clean build
  [image]
- If none of the above steps fixes your problem then try creating a new web application and add all of your jar files again.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but unfortunately I am still receiving a 500 error.

Comment: no problem, how are you setting up your project ? can you upload it to a website or https://github.com. I might be able to help you.

Comment: I had the project set up in eclipse.  It is now working.  Thank you for your help